# Maven: Is real to recompile from source artefact?

Tags: java, maven

we have some dependency xxx-1.0.jar with it xxx-1.0-source.jar (built using maven) real sources was lost, but xxx-1.0-source.jar contain source.

Now I need make some changes in this source, any easy way to do it and compile back?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to unzip the jar file and reconstruct the build system.  But I have to ask, how did you "lose" the source?

Comment: So, one company, make that code deprecated but continue use it in a product :) but they don`t want to provide deprecated code and removed it from git repository.

Comment: Ok.  It's worth checking what the license for that source code allows you to do, then.

Comment: No backup / no version control system? Which is backed up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it is built with maven and if you have both compiled and source jars,  there is an easy way to do that.

create an empty folder with your project name and create following folder structure.

```
MyProject
 |--src
 |   |--main
 |       |--java
 |--pom.xml
```

After that extract the complied jar and you should be able to find `pom.xml` file within `META-INF` folder. copy and past it to your project pom file.
Then extract source code jar file and copy source code into `src > main > java` folder which you have created.

Now you can open your project folder with any IDE as a maven project. You can build it by running command `mvn clean install`

Comment: Thx for solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is pretty generic, so here comes a generic answer:

- extract that source code JAR
- create a new project in your favorite IDE
- import/load that source code
- keep massaging until it compiles
- understand the required settings, and turn your project into a "built system" built thing

In other words: you still have the source code, now you probably have to re-build the **meta** information that is required to compile that source code successfully.

Comment: Maybe world have some tools for that :)